# Регистрация в Битрикс24

Tags: windows, 1с, установка, битрикс24, crm

Скачал Битрикс24 с [Битрикс24 для Windows и Mac](https://www.bitrix24.ru/features/desktop.php)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустил скачанный файл и сделал первые 2 шага для регистрации Битрикс24

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на 3-ем шаге выдало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На последнем шаге нет кнопок для нажатия. Следующая кнопка не нажимается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать для того, чтобы перейти на следующий 4-й шаг?